# Centering text with Bootstrap 2.3.1

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

From searching around, I know this question has been asked before and I just... don't understand what is going wrong here.

I have tried about a million different angles and just can't get my text to center.

If anyone has any idea what the deal is and would like to let me know, that would be great.

```
<div class="row-fluid text-center">
    <h1 class="span12">Foobar's Contacts</h1>
</div>
```

Among other things, I already tried moving the `text-center` class to the `h1` element.

EDIT: I was able to change it to this and center the header. Any drawbacks to this approach?

```
<div class="offset4 span4 text-center">
    <h1 class="span8">Foobar's Contacts</h1>
</div>
```

Comment: [What exactly is the problem?](http://jsfiddle.net/QFrFA/)

Comment: Well, the problem is that I can't center the text on the page. I have seen people do it in this way but it doesn't seem to work for me?

Comment: Is there at all a chance that you have an overriding style - i.e. something more specific - that has a text-align: left rule in it?

Answer (score 0):

Try putting `<h1>` within a `<div>` specifying the span. Something like

```
<div class="row-fluid">
    <div class="span12 text-center">
        <h1>name's Contacts</h1>
    </div>
</div>
```

I don't really understand though if you are trying to center a text within a `<div>`, or the entire page. If you want your page to be centered use something like

```html
<div class="container">
    .
    .
    <div class="row-fluid">
        <div class="span12 text-center">
            <h1>name's Contacts</h1>
        </div>
    </div>
    .
    .
</div>
```

Hope it helps.